# Overlaying virtual element on the controller resulting in wrong scale

Tags: graphics, 3d, augmented-reality, aframe, virtual-reality

We are currently trying to create a virtual object ( A plane ) and overlay it on the controller of a Magic Leap Device. However, we are having some difficulties doing this.
When I set the width or any dimension of an entity to say 1 meter. The resulting virtual image is not 1 meter and actually smaller.

Also, It seems like the image does on stay at the same position relative to the controller when we move it around. There seems to be a offset that magic leap adds.

```
  <a-entity id="controller" magicleap-controls="hand: right">
        <a-plane id="board" width="0.45" height="0.1" position="0 0 0.0" rotation="-45 0 0" color="#b3b3b3" material="side: double; transparent: true; opacity: 0.5">
        </a-plane>
</a-entity>
```

This is the code I am using. I am essentially trying to create a virtual board (which will map to the physical board -- but the sizes are not lining up)

What could be the issue?? Any leads would be appreciated

Comment: does it have any parent nodes with defined scale/ position attributes? This may change the plane size

Comment: Yes, it does! We wrap a few boxes around a plane to make it easier to move around. However, the parent node does not have scale but only position attributes.. not sure if that would affect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be caused by the parent node's attributes. In A-Frame every entity inherits **position, scale, and rotation** from its parent element. The child element inherits that and marks it in its **local space** as [0 0 0] (or [1 1 1] for scale) and that can be whatever else in **world space**. Any child transformation will be applied on top of that.

**quick edit** - not only the direct parent will have an effect but every single entity that is wrapping the final element.

source - [relative-positioning](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/position.html#relative-positioning)

#### Look at the example below

there are 2 spheres that are identical but one is wrapped in another entity with changed attributes. Look what happens - it gets distorted and displaced as the transformation is applied to its **local space**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene>
          <a-entity position="-6 0 -5" scale="2 2 1">
            <a-sphere scale="1 2 3" position="3 1 -5" color="blue"> </a-sphere>
          </a-entity>
          <a-sphere scale="1 2 3" position="3 1 -5" color="red"> </a-sphere>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I will attempt this :)